# Login With Google Access Control Using GSuite Groups

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-workspace

We are trying to implement a "Login With Google" feature for an internal admin dashboard web app connected to our GSuite account. We want to limit login to this dashboard in two ways.

1. Only members of our GSuite domain can login to the dashboard
2. Only users in our domain belonging to a specific group within our domain can login to the dashboard

So far we have been able to accomplish number 1 above but not 2. Using a query param to the oauth2 API we can limit the domain. What we have in mind to accomplish number 2 is after the user within our domain is logged in, get their group information and validate that they are in the proper internal group or log them out. The issue with this is it seems only GSuite admin accounts are allowed to make API calls to the Directory API for this information. Is there no way to get the group information for a user with their own access token or using a service account? Ideally we don't want to have to provide a specific admin user within our GSuite account's personal credentials in our application to get this working. Is there a better way to proceed?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: It seems that you are planning to use [G Suite Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory). I don't think ordinary user's token will be enough. You may use a Service Account (SA) if you need a preauthorized (no consent screen will appear) server to server communication but, even with SA, you will need more authorization than a normal user. You should, when creating your `Credentials`, impersonate an admin of that hosted domain of yours. What about creating a particular user just for this task and make it admin?

Comment: If necessary to make a specific account for this, we prefer to use a service account since my understanding is that this is the sort of thing they are meant for. However, we were unable to get it to have admin privileges. When you say "impersonate an admin" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: When requesting APIs services you must create your `Credentials` object before using `Service`; `Credentials` contains (among other things) the email of your Service Account/SA (the one ending with `gserviceaccount.com`) and other stuff that identifies your SA. Since `G Suite Admin SDK` is not called "Admin" by coincidence, you need to impersonate the admin of the domain (in your `Credentials`) after the domain admin granted, in his admin console, your SA Client ID the right scopes (permissions) you are asking to use. Read https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation